# Django - how can I save cart items in a session

Tags: django, python-3.x, session

in my django ecommerce I want to save session data for users not logged in. About saving cart ind DB, updating and retrieving it for logged users it's all ok, but how I can proceed for guest users? I tried in this way, but I think this is not a good solution: I save id cart in session and whole cart in database..Could you help me?

This is my views.py:

```
def update_cart(request, slug):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
      #ok here...
    else:
        try:
            the_id = request.session["cart_id"]
        except:
            new_cart = Cart()
            product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
            new_cart.save()
            request.session["cart_id"] = new_cart.id
            new_cart.products.add(product)
            new_cart.save()
            return HttpResponse("<h1>okkk!</h1>") 



        cart = Cart.objects.get(id = the_id)
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=slug)
        if not product in cart.products.all():
            cart.products.add(product)
            cart.save()    
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
        else:
            cart.products.remove(product)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("cart"))
```

and they are my Cart model and Product model:

```
    class Cart(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete="CASCADE", null=True)
        products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, blank=True)
        updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
        timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


        def __str__(self):
            return str(self.id)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100, default=29.99)
    image = models.FileField(upload_to="products/images", blank=True, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('title', 'slug')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Is it not working? Using the session to save data for non authenticated users is perfectly valid. You just may want to think of a way to delete carts and cart items for sessions that have expired.

Comment: It's working, but I don't want to save cart in DB for not logged users, just in session..It's a good practice to save cart in database for not logged users?

Comment: You can save the entire cart in your session if you don't want to save it directly in the db. As long as the data you put in the cart is serialisable, that would work. In your case, you could just save the product ids and amount for each product id. Saving to db isn't bad practice either (the session is saved to db, by default), but again, you probably want to link the cart to the session so it gets deleted when the session gets deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a dictionary to populate all the necessary information of a product like this

```
product_document = {
   'title': product.title,
   'price': product.price
}
```

And you can use this to store in the session with the key 'cart' which is an empty dictionary at the beginning and perform adding, updating and deleting of product_document as you would do with any dictionary element.

For example adding a product to the cart would be:

```
request.session['cart'] = {}
request.session['cart'][str(product.id)] = product_document
```

Comment: This was helpful @Lag11, you saved my day :) My suggest is to serialize this cart with all items:

data = serializers.serialize('json', new_cart.products.all())

Comment: Yes, that would keep things organized. The book "Django by Example" by Antonio Mele has a section on building a shopping cart. I use this book as a reference whenever I come across something very common but new to me. I suggest you skim through it and keep it as a handbook for the future.